# Check if one object is related to another with Datamapper

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

Using Codeigniter and [Datamapper](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/): I have 2 tables: **tags** and **clients**. Clients can have many tags, tags can have many clients. I am using a separate join table to save the relationships.

I have a page for managing an individual tag, where I am iterating through every client, and want to check if each one is related to this tag.

The `????` in the code below determines if the checkbox is checked, it should be `TRUE` if the client has the tag, `FALSE` if not.

```
<h2>Manage Tag: <?php echo $tag->name; ?></h2>

<?php foreach ($clients as $client): ?>

    <label>
        <?php echo form_checkbox('client_id[]', $client->id, ????); ?>
        <?php echo $client->name; ?>
    </label>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

How can I check if `$client` is related to `$tag` in this loop with [Datamapper](http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
$client->is_related_to($tag)
```

or

```
$client->is_related_to('tag', $tag->id)
```

See http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/count.html#is_related_to

Note that this will fire additional count() queries, you might be better of fetching $tag->clients, and then check in your loop if

```
isset($tag->clients->all[$client->id])
```

Comment: Per your edit: I could not get the second solution did to work, would I need to enable `all_array_uses_ids` or something? My original workaround was looping once through `$tag->client`, throwing the client ids in an array, and then using `in_array($client->id, $related_tag_ids)` which produces no (or less) extra queries. I'll have to take a look at the generated queries and see what is happening. Sometimes efficiency is better than elegance.

Comment: Bit late, but yes, you need 'all_array_uses_ids'. I have that default in every application, so I forgot to mention that, sorry...